# Open Unicenta code in netbeans to edit its code

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Hi :) Now I need to edit in Unicenta code but i found 2 problems 
1)First problem: I didn't find any URL to download source code although I could download exe file and when I make search about source code I found this URL and it'snot working https://unicenta.comdownloads/
2)Second problem: when I make search about editing code of unicenta I didn't find any results so I think that I have wrong idea about editing unicenta.
So any body has idea about unicenta if I can edit its code or not

Answer (score 0):

The code is indeed editable, using Netbeans. By doing a minimal amount of searching using Google and the Unicenta website, I came across [this Sourceforge page], which allows downloading ZIP archives of the source code.

The instructions at the bottom of that page mention that Netbeans can be used, by opening a file called `pom.xml`. This file is used to describe how the project should be built using a build system known as Maven. For example, it can describe steps such as packaging resources into jars, performing code generation, or simply fetching libraries that are dependencies. Netbeans should be equipped to handle this by default. Alternatively, you may use IntelliJ IDEA (also capable of handling maven projects) or Eclipse with a plug-in.